# Inequality involving Hadamard's inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A$ be matrix in $\mathbb{R^{m \times n}}$. Let $A$ and $B$ be *quadratic submatrices* of $M$ such that $\det(A)< \det(B)$.

Does this imply $\prod_{i=1}^n \|A^i\| < \prod_{i=1}^n \|B^i\|$ (using *Hadamard's inequality*), where $A^i$ and $B^i$ denotes the columns of $A$ and $B$, respectively.

Comment: What is a quadratic submatrix?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please show us what you have tried so far, and define things like quadratic submatrices and Hadamard's inequality.

Comment: I suppose that *quadratic* is a (literal?) translation, actually meaning *square*. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality)'s a Wikipedia link for Hadamard's inequality, for everyone's benefit.

Comment: By the way, the first $A$ should actually be $M$ (otherwise the statement doesn't make sense).

Comment: No, it's just a vector norm (he did say that the $A^i$ and $B^i$ are columns of some matrices).

Comment: I don't see what the matrix $M$ has to do with anything. It seems to me that there should be a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood the question correctly, this is a counterexample:

Let 
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}
10 &  0  & 0\\
0  &  10 & 10\\
0  &   0       & 0
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

$$B=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 &  0  & 0\\
0  &  1 & 0\\
0  &   0       & 1
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Then $0=\det(A)<\det(B)=1$, but $\prod_{i=1}^3 \|a_i\|  \ge \prod_{i=1}^3 \|b_i\|$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that being submatrices of a given matrix is actually necessary. Indeed, given any two $n\times n$ matrices you can always concatenate them to form a $n\times 2n$ matrix of witch (by construction) they both are square submatrices).

As a counterexample to your question, consider the matrices
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $\det(A)=\frac{1}{2}<1=\det(B)$ but
$$
\prod_{i=1}^2 \|A^i\| = \sqrt{4+\frac{1}{4}} = \frac{\sqrt{17}}{2} > 1 = \prod_{i=1}^2 \|B^i\|
$$